# How to use radio buttons with Angular ng-repeat on a Rails collection, with a default value

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm an Angular newbie, and am having issues with using ng-repeat against a Rails collection.

I have a Rails collection of accounts associated to a user:
current_user.accounts

I'm trying to use ng-repeat to iterate through the collection, and have radio buttons for the user to select a primary account.  The radio button should be set to whichever is the current primary account (as determined by an attribute on account, account.is_primary = true).  Can't seem to get it to work at all.  This is what I'm vaguely trying to do:

```
    table.pure-table.pure-table-striped
  thead
    tr
      th Name
      th Account
      th Primary Account

  tbody ng-controller="MiscAccountCtrl"
    div ng-repeat="account in accounts"
      tr.collapsible
        td
          .slider ng-class="isOpen"
            .cell-container {{ account.account_type }}
        td
          .slider ng-class="isOpen"
            .cell-container= {{ account.name }}
        td
          .slider ng-class="isOpen"
            .cell-container
              input type="radio" ng-model="primary" ng-change='setPrimary(#{ account.id })'
```

The specific problems I am having are:
1) can't figure out how to bind the Rails collection (current_user.accounts) to a $scope variable such that I can do "account in accounts".
2) how to have the radio buttons pre-selected to whichever is the current primary account

I think I have a sense of how to do the rest, i.e. how to set the new primary once a new radio button is selected (using ng-change to call a directive), but can't get the basic setup right.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

dc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem you have is not binding an object to `ng-model`. The `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for every repeated item. When you use a primitive in `ng-model` it loses 2 way binding in the child scope because primitives don't have inheritance.

So start with an object in controller so that this object gets inherited by child scopes. `ng-model` will take care of creating object properties if they don't already exist

```
$scope.formData ={};
```

Then in html:

```
input type="radio" ng-model="formData.primary"
```

> Golden Rule: Always have a **dot** in `ng-model` ....or `[]`